# Bangla subtitle(connected letter) problem in VLC and gnome-mplayer

Tags: fonts, vlc, mplayer, unicode, subtitle

I am trying to run a `srt` file written in unicode Bangla. I have changed the encoding settings to `UTF-8` and select a Bangla unicode font in VLC subtitle settings.

I can see normal letter but not `connected letters` (i.e ক + ে = কে). Same thing is happening in `gnome-mplayer`.

Is any media player can render complex Bangla unicode in screen?

## screenshot of latest VLC player

[image]

**Note: I already installed Bangla Language/support package.**

Answer (score 0):

you can use smplayer to solve bangla subtitle problem in ubuntu and other linux operating systems

1. install smplayer and set it as a default player
2. click right button of your mouse and go to smplayer's preferences
3. Encoding: select UTF-8
4. check Try to autodetect for this language and select Bengali(bn)
5. Apply and Ok
6. if subtitle is too small press Shift+T to enlarge,  and Shift+R to
   make it small..

now everything ok....

thanks... Oronno BAU
{ search me in Google }

Answer (score 0):

Go to `preference` in VLC. Head over to `Subtitles/OSD` option. Set the `font` as **Lohit Bengali**[(Like this).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CMCj.jpg)

VLC have some issue with `.srt` format try using `.ass` subtitle file. You can rename a `.srt` to .`ass` as well, or You can try [mpv player](https://mpv.io/)

To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests
sudo apt update && sudo apt install mpv
```

To uninstall:

```
sudo apt remove mpv && sudo apt autoremove
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert the subtitle to .ass format, use Aegisub for convert it.

```
sudo apt-get install aegisub
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, You should share more info about this, not just few words. Honestly, I already flagged it as low quality in the review queue. Later, I checked that this workaround should work. The idea behind it is that most video players uses libass to render `.ass/.ssa` subtitle file types. Where libass had already implemented [harfbuzz](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/HarfBuzz/) support (Unicode shaping engine), where other subtitles are handled by the player.

Comment: You deserve an up vote from me, if add some words to explain. Or you may just copy from my comment :).